# How to regex a string - length 8, first character letter and remaining numeric

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a RegEx to match a string with the following criterion

- Length 8
- First character must be a letter a-z or A-Z
- The remaining 7 must be numeric 0-9

examples

- a5554444
- B9999999
- c0999999

This is what I have so far

```
^[0-9]{8}$
```

What am I missing to check the first character? I tried

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{8}$
```

but that's not working.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{7}$
```

the {...} metacharacter only matches the most previous pattern which in your case is [0-9]. the regex interpretation is as follows:

1. start at the beginning of the string (^)
2. match any character a-z or A-Z ([a-zA-Z]) in the first spot only one time
3. match any character 0-9 starting at the second spot ([0-9])
4. the preceding pattern mentioned in step 3 of [0-9] must exist exactly 7 times ({7})

When you put {8} as per your original question, you'll assume a string length total of 9: the first character being alphabetic case insensitive and the remaining 8 characters being numeric.

Comment: Here is a site for building regular expressions. [regex101](https://regex101.com)